# Decrypt Modulr secure token

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography, rsa

In my Flutter App I need to decrypt a secure token from the Modulr API.
First I need to generate a RSA key and Modulr will use it to generate a secure token.

When the token is generated I receive a encryptedSymmetricKey, a initialisationVector (iv) and a token I need to decrypt.

The encryptedSymmetricKey is encoded using RSA ECB cipher with OAEP and with a hash SHA-256.

Then with the decrypted encryptedSymmetricKey I can decrypt the token encoded with a  AES GCM cipher with no padding.

I'm using the pointycastle package.

This is my code:

```
  /// DECRYPT SYMMETRIC KEY
  final p = OAEPEncoding.withSHA256(RSAEngine());

  p.init(false, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(modulrKey.keypair.privateKey.asPointyCastle));

  final decryptedSymetricKeyBytes = p.process(base64Decode(result.encryptedSymmetricKey));

  /// AES-GCM ALGO
  final algo = AesGcm.with128bits();

  /// DECODE INIT VECTOR
  final decodedIv = base64Decode(result.initialisationVector);

  /// AES KEY
  final aesKey = await algo.newSecretKeyFromBytes(decryptedSymetricKeyBytes);

  /// DECRYPT TOKEN
  final decodedToken = base64Decode(result.token);

  final secretBox = SecretBox(decodedToken, nonce: decodedIv, mac: Mac.empty);
  final decryptedTokenBytes = await algo.decrypt(secretBox, secretKey: aesKey);
  final decryptedToken = base64Encode(decryptedTokenBytes);
```

But when I execute it I get this error:

> SecretBox has wrong message authentication code (MAC)

Any idea how I can resolve this error??

Additionally, this is the Modlur documentation: https://modulr.readme.io/docs/retrieve-secure-card-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked JavaScript and Java code](https://modulr.readme.io/docs/retrieve-secure-card-details#encryption-code-examples) show that `decodedToken` is the concatenation of the actual ciphertext and the 16 bytes GCM tag. However, since the [*cryptography*](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) package used in the Dart code processes the ciphertext and the tag independently, both portions must first be separated. Then they can be passed to [`SecretBox`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/SecretBox-class.html). The decrypted data must be UTF-8 decoded.

A possible fix is:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
...
// Separate ciphertext and tag
final decodedToken = base64Decode(result.token);
final token  = decodedToken.sublist(0, decodedToken.length - 16);
final tag = decodedToken.sublist(decodedToken.length - 16);
...
// Apply ciphertext and tag
final secretBox = SecretBox(token, nonce: decodedIv, mac: Mac(tag));
...
// Utf-8 decode
final decryptedToken = utf8.decode(decryptedTokenBytes);
```

With this, the posted Dart code is functionally identical to the linked JavaScript and Java code, respectively.